# Java Data Modeling: Use Map or List to build one to many relationship

Tags: java, mongodb, relational-database, relationship, data-modeling

Use Case: A person can have many telephone numbers. The clients are sending the following JSON to the server, which shall store it into a databases:

```
{
    "personName": "John Smith",
    "telephoneNumbers": {
       "id-1234": {
          "number": "01-456546546",
          "type": "private"
       },
        "id-1235": {
          "number": "01-1456546",
          "type": "office"
       }
    }
}
```

The model class for person could be like this (variant map):

```
public class  Person {
     private String personName;
     private Map<String, TelephoneNumber>;
}
```

Or like this (variant list):

```
public class  Person {
     private String personName;
     private List<TelephoneNumber>;
}
```

The model class for telephone number could be like this:

```
public class TelephoneNumber {
    private String id; // for variant list
    private String number;
    private String type;
}
```

My thoughts:
This data model Person variant list is conventional und universal. But I have to write a mapper to map the input JSON to this Person model.

For the data model Person variant map, I could deserialize the JSON and store the object directly to DB. But I am afraid it would only work for NoSQL DB, because I think it is difficult to annotate one-to-many relationship for a relational DB for a Java Map.

Do you have any suggestions to prefer variant list or map?

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is justified.

It is always a good and safe solution to keep the `id` of a given entity as a property of itself.

This means that the solution with the `List` is better for both NoSQL and Relational databases IMHO.

Also you could find many framework with DSL languages such as Spring DSL which have a better integration and comprehension of the second design than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am doing. if get a better solution. Store to DB has a list and get has map.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    // ... some codes here
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<TelephoneNumber> telephoneNumbers;

    @Transient
    private Map<Long, TelephoneNumber> telephoneNumbersMap;

    public Map<Long, TelephoneNumber> getTelephoneNumbersMap() {
        if (telephoneNumbers != null) {
            for (TelephoneNumber telephoneNumber : telephoneNumbers) {
                telephoneNumbersMap.put(telephoneNumber.getId(), telephoneNumber);
            }
        }
        return telephoneNumbersMap;
    }

    // ... rest of codes
}
```

Comment: In your solution the getTelephoneNumbersMap is actually also a mapper. It means I have to have a mapper to write to and a mapper to read from DB anyway.